# Can I get the number of a case statement in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement

I have a switch statement like this:

```
switch (int) {
        case 0:
                // do x
            break;
        case 1:
                // do y
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Can I get the case number?

The reason I ask is that I have a method in each one that would use a variable int.  For example:

```
switch (int) {
        case 0:
                [self doMethod:string setTag:  <CASE NUMBER>  ];
            break;
        case 1:
                [self doMethod:string setTag:  <CASE NUMBER>  ];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just use the original variable?

Comment: @SLaks - sometimes we all start overthinking these things. +1

Comment: @SLaks **facepalm** .............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
switch (x) {
    case 0:
        // if you're here, you know x == 0
        [self doMethod:string setTag: x];
        break;
    ...
}
```

But unless `string` is a different variable or literal in each case, this doesn't make much sense; you could as easily say

```
if (x == 0 || x == 1) {
    [self doMethod: string setTag: x];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, you can't do `switch (int)`. `int` is a data type. You need a variable in there.

Then all you need to do is reference the variable in the `case` statement:

```
int someVar = ... // some value
switch (someVar) {
    case 0:
        [self doMethod:string setTag:someVar];
        break;
    case 1:
        [self doMethod:string setTag:someVar];
        break;
}
```

BTW - if you do the same thing for multiple cases you can do:

```
int someVar = ... // some value
switch (someVar) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
        [self doMethod:string setTag:someVar];
        break;
    default:
        // other stuff
        break;
}
```

And as Josh pointed out, depending on your needs, this whole thing could simply be:

```
int someVar = ... // some value
[self doMethod:string setTag:someVar];
```

or maybe:

```
int someVar = ... // some value
if (someVar >= 0 && someVar <= 1) {
    [self doMethod:string setTag:someVar];
}
```

Comment: I was using int as a replacement of a variable.  But I just realized how stupid I was being... Oh well c'est la vie.

Comment: I know you're answer was more in depth, but you were a minute behind, so I'm going to have to give this to @cHao.

Comment: Fine but mine was actually 1st. :)